# Let $A$ be ans open rectificable set in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Given the point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $p_n>0$, let $S$ be the subset of

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

I have problems trying to find a diffeomorphism of $A\times (0,1)$ with $S$, how could this be done? I think that if this is done, the question in (b) would be easy. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try sending (a,t) to $(1-t)a + tp$

Comment: @AreaMan 
Would that be injective?

Comment: yes. Note that A is in R^(n-1), and p has positive nth component. So if two points in the domain are mapped to the same place, in particular if their nth components in the image are equal, then the t values of the starting points were equal